# Using merge_asof() without replacement

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two DataFrames (df1 and df2 respectively):

```
df1 = 

                      Type       Price  Size
Dates                                       
2019-08-16 00:00:34  TRADE  130.859375     1
2019-08-16 00:00:57  TRADE  130.859375     5
2019-08-16 00:00:57  TRADE  130.859375     2
2019-08-16 00:01:00  TRADE  130.859375     8

df2 = 

                              Trade Price Trade Volume
Time                                                  
2019-08-16 00:00:34.875364542     130.859            1
2019-08-16 00:00:57.720986127     130.859            5
2019-08-16 00:00:57.731894016     130.859            2
2019-08-16 00:01:00.093161344     130.859            8
```

df1's times are not as precise as df2's times, meaning I cannot merge on the indices alone. Furthermore, it is not guaranteed that they are the same length (I cannot just concatenate them).

I've been attempting to use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to merge on the closest times:

```
mergedData = pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), left_on=['Dates'], right_on=['Time'], direction='nearest')
```

It seems like once a match is made, it is still available as a potential match and therefor a time such as `2019-08-16 00:00:57` will be matched with `2019-08-16 00:00:57.720986127` twice. Is there any possible solution?

Comment: This can get very complicated. For instance if your times in `df2` were [00:34.1, 00;57.1, 01:00.1, 01:00.4] it's somewhat ambiguous as to how you could match that. That is, should you match 00:57 with 01:00.1, and 00:01:00 with 01:00.4 to minimize the overall time difference, or 00:01:00 with 01:00.1 and the second 00:57 with 01:00.4, since you'd still want to prioritize the closest time for dates when possible, then fix the rest that get duplicated after the fact?

Comment: On the other hand, why not just specify that there must be an exact match on 'Trade Volume' and 'Size' in addition to the asof merge on the date/time?

Comment: what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

try to fit the time format before merging

```
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'], format= '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['time'], format= '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because you haven't specified the logic on how to merge multiple rows close to each other in time. Furthermore, `merge_asof()` can only do left merges, so you wouldn't even be able to do a full outer join and then sort out the duplicates in the result.

From the example you give, a weak assumption is that you can may perhaps rely on volume to disambiguate multiple same-second rows in `df1`.

If that assumption holds on your entire data, then you can request an exact match on volume:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(
    df2.reset_index(),
    df1.reset_index(),
    left_by='Trade Volume', right_by='Size',
    left_on=['Time'], right_on=['Dates'], direction='nearest')

# df3:
                           Time  Trade Price  Trade Volume  Size  \
0 2019-08-16 00:00:34.875364542      130.859             1     1   
1 2019-08-16 00:00:57.720986127      130.859             5     5   
2 2019-08-16 00:00:57.731894016      130.859             2     2   
3 2019-08-16 00:01:00.093161344      130.859             8     8   

                Dates   Type       Price  
0 2019-08-16 00:00:34  TRADE  130.859375  
1 2019-08-16 00:00:57  TRADE  130.859375  
2 2019-08-16 00:00:57  TRADE  130.859375  
3 2019-08-16 00:01:00  TRADE  130.859375
```

You can also reduce the redundant information (which I presume you left in for debugging purposes):

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df2.rename(columns={'Trade Volume': 'Size'}), df1,
    by='Size', left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='nearest')

# df3:
                               Trade Price  Size   Type       Price
Time                                                               
2019-08-16 00:00:34.875364542      130.859     1  TRADE  130.859375
2019-08-16 00:00:57.720986127      130.859     5  TRADE  130.859375
2019-08-16 00:00:57.731894016      130.859     2  TRADE  130.859375
2019-08-16 00:01:00.093161344      130.859     8  TRADE  130.859375
```

But the big caveat is that assumption above. Please expand your example if it doesn't hold, and please provide the expected output along with the logic.